# Find all values of $ r $ such that $ a_n = r^n $ for $ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge2} $ in a recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given the following recurrence relation:
\begin{equation}
a_n = 6a_{n-1} - 8a_{n-2} \ \text{ for } \ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge2}
\end{equation}

Find all values of $ r $ so that when $ a_0 = 1 $ and $ a_1 = r $ then $ a_n = r^n \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

My attempt:

\begin{align}
\text{By distinct roots theorem,} \\ \\
\text{Characteristic equation: }
& t^2 - 6t + 8 = 0 \\
& (t-3)^2 + 8 - 9 = 0 \\
& (t-3)^2 = 1 \\
& t = 4 \text{ or } t = 2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text{Let } a_0 = 1 = C(4^0) + D(2^0) \text{ where C, D } \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
1 = C + D \\
C = 1 - D
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{Let } a_1 = r &= C(4) + D(2) \\
r &= 4C + 2D \\
r &= 4(1-D) + 2D \quad \text{(By substitution)} \\
r &= 4 - 4D + 2D \\
r &= 4 - 2D
\end{align}

It seems that I must have gone wrong somewhere as $ r < 0 $ for $ D > 2$. Hence the answer for $ a_n $ would be very strange (i.e. $ a_n < 0 $ when $ r = -4 $). Could anyone please assist me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By substituting $a_n$ by $r^n$, you get $r^n = 6 r^{n-1} -8r^{n-2}$ for $n\ge2$.

Thus $r^2 - 6r + 8 =0$ hence $r \in \{2, 4\}$ as you rightly figured out.

The issue with what you did is that you tried to solve the equations once you had $a_n = C 4^n + D 2^n$. You should have figured that either $C = 0$ and $D = 1$ or $D = 0$ and $C = 1$ (or else there exists no $r \in \Bbb R$ such that $\forall n\in \Bbb N, a_n = r^n$)

Comment: How do you make use of the initial conditions in obtaining the value of r?

Comment: This is the point : you don't.

Comment: Why are the initial conditions irrelevant here?

Comment: Because you are trying to find a sequence with a global property that does not only rely on the initial conditions rather than expliciting it from the initial conditions. The fact that your sequence is geometric is something that concerns every term of the sequence, not only the first two.

Comment: Hi @Astyx, could you elaborate on how was (C = 0, D = 1) and (C = 1, D = 0) obtained?

Comment: @KeithOYS The first part of my answer ensures that $r\in \{2,4\}$. Once you have this, simply solve 
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
C+D &= 1\\
4C+2D &= 2\\
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$
or
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
C+D &= 1\\
4C+2D &= 4\\
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$ depending on $r$

Comment: Thank you @Astyx. Since the question asks `Find all values of r`, would the roots `r = 2, r = 4` suffice or does it require constant values of C and D as well?

Comment: @KeithOYS What I would answer is first that if $a_n = r^n$, then $r\in\{2,4\}$ (see my answer) thus the only solutions are among $\{2,4\}$. Then if $r\in \{2,4\}$ and $a_n = r^n$ and $a_{n+1} = r^{n+1}$, we have $a_{n+2} = (6r + 8)r^n = r^{n+2}$ thus $2$ and $4$ are solutions. Therefore the solutions are $r=2$ and $r=4$. No need to solve the general form of sequences verifying this equation.

Comment: Hi @LanceHAOH, may I check with you, did you obtain $a_n = 1/2(2^n) + 3/2(4^n)$ for part (b)?

Comment: @KeithOYS I cannot remember. But since it is a solution to a recurrence, you can check your answer using recurrence solvers like wolframalpha.

Answer (score 1):

Both roots give solutions: $r=4$ for $a_n = 4^n$ ($C=0, D=1$) and $r=2$ for $a_n = 2^n$ ($C=1, D=0$).

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on how was (C = 0, D = 1) and (C = 1, D = 0) obtained?

Comment: The whole point of the characteristic equation is that it is what you need to make $a_n = r^n$ a solution to the recursion.

Comment: Understood, thank you!